# Error logging in with Gmail OpenID

Tags: bug, status-completed, openid, login

I think I know why this is happening, but not sure how to fix it.

1. I first created a skeptics exchange account with an @live.com email address.
2. I then created a stackoverflow account by logging in with my gmail openid, which associated the account with my @gmail.com email address
3. I then deleted stackoverflow account (my intention was to link my accounts, and I hadn't realized my skeptics account was using my @live.com address).
4. I then logged into skeptics, associated my current account (with the live.com email) with my gmail openid (my original intention)
5. I then went back to stackoverflow and logged in with my gmail openID - so that I could link the two accounts.
6. I got an error, and cannot login to stack overflow. I'm pretty sure it's because I now have a deleted account and a linked account both associated with the same openid.

I got an error message when I used the OpenID to create a Meta account as well, but after refreshing the page I was logged in. Still can't get into Stack Overflow, though.

Comment: Looking into this now...

Comment: Hopefully the experience hasn't left you feeling.. skeptical

Answer (score 6):

We currently have an automated task that takes care of merging users and accounts, but your step 3 threw it for a loop - it was in the middle of a merge when the Stack Overflow user was deleted.  This left your account in a bad state.

I've fixed your account and you should be able to create a new user on Stack Overflow that will have all of your credentials available to it and be associated to your other users.

Also, we'll fix this loophole so future users won't get in this bugged state.