# Logging in to Stack Overflow using Gmail on iPad

Tags: bug, login, google-openid, ipad

I use Gmail authentication through SO, and when I try to log in on my iPad (which appears to be the full, non-mobile version of SO), I click the "Login with Gmail" link and nothing happens.  On my Mac, the icon highlights with yellow and redirects to Gmail's login page...

I know this question has been asked before... Examples include [Cannot log in with iPad anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177639/cannot-log-in-with-ipad-anymore) and [Error logging in with Gmail OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131540/error-logging-in-with-gmail-openid), but those are extremely old, and as far as I know, there's no way to bump a question to effectively say "this is now a problem again."

Suggestions or thoughts?

Comment: "no way to bump a question" Bounty?

Comment: @grgarside If old bug reports have been fixed and recur again, it's better to create a new question instead of bumping the old one anyway.

Comment: Plus it's "cheaper" to create a new question, with respect to giving up what little precious reputation on meta that I have...

Comment: @CDub feel free to ping me anytime (comment on one of my posts) and ask to "bountify" something explaining why - I got 13K spare rep that is totally meaningless anyway. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Ha!  I'll get there... someday... ;)

Comment: No repro in IE6.

Comment: @AnnaLear actually that one was never fixed. Going to put a bounty. :)